# Homebrewのインストールができません。

Tags: macos, homebrew

Mac(Yosemite 10.10.5)でHomebrewのインストールができません。

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL    https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

> curl: (56) SSLRead() return error -9806

SSL系のエラーで証明書の設定ということで、日本語の文章少なく難航しております。

```
/usr ls
```

> X11       bin     lib     share X11R6     include     libexec     sbin        standalone

また調べたらlocalなどのファイルもなくなっているみたいです。
関係あるかわかりませんが、その他の情報も載せておきます。
以前はOS 10.11 Capitanでhomebrewも使えておりました。
しか作業中にerror -9806が返ってきて、それが直せなかったので本日MacのクリーンインストールでYosemiteを入れなおしてみました。しかし状況が変わってなく、現在立ち止まってるところです。

状況判断できる方いましたらコメントいただけますでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `GitHub`だとTLSを使うサーバかと思いますが、Macの`SecureTransport`が`TLS`に対応していないのが原因かも…別のOpenSSLライブラリを使えば良いような気がします。あと`ruby`の`OpenSSL::X509::DEFAULT_CERT_FILE`に`pem`が無いとか……

Comment: Myakuさん
コメントありがとうございました。
結果お伝えしますとハック的なのはなくて、力技でクリーンインストール(今度は3回上書き消去する方法)で解決しました。
Macでの作業諦めてLinuxのパーテーション作ってそちらで作業しようかと思ってました。ありがとうございました！！